Broken BraceWrapping in clang-format in presence of an empty macro
I have the following code
enum MyFlag SOME_EMPTY_MACRO( ARG ) 
{
  MyEnumValue = 1 << 1 //!< ...
};

In my clang-format, I have BraceWrapping.AfterEnum: true
This always get transformed to (opening brace going on the line before)
enum MyFlag SOME_EMPTY_MACRO( ARG ) {
  MyEnumValue = 1 << 1 //!< ...
};

Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

By defining the macros (since version 17), it worked as expected:
Macros:
  - SOME_EMPTY_MACRO(x)=x

